# Expose a field from a Class and add a property?

Tags: c#, class, properties

I have a silly problem and I am possibly going about this the wrong way.

I want to add a property to a class to change a field. I am thinking that this is not possible due to the Class level of protection.

SEE: [Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.PWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.pwm(v=vs.102).aspx) I want my code to modify this Class.

I want to change the Boolean:

```
bool invert;
```

in the initialisation of the Class:

```
PWM pwm = new PWM(Cpu.PWMChannel.PWM_4, 10, 0.5, true);
```

I want to be able to access the true variable and modify it. At will that is outside of creating a new instance.

I have tried:

```
public partial class PWM : Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.PWM
{
private static bool invert;

protected static bool Invert
{
get { return invert; }
set { invert = value; }
}
}
```

I think this is a failure anyone have any ideas to expose this as a property?

Comment: Why is the code as shown a problem or "a failure"? Does it work?

Comment: No not as it is. It gives me the field. But I have to add a ton of other methods and so on which seems to be non constructive as I don't know them. Why the -1?

Comment: You can't expose private fields from base classes in a derived class. Also, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Thanks! I thought this was going to be a FAIL. I meant a general What? Why? to the down vote, not directed at anyone except the down voter. Thanks +1 ;O)

Answer (score 1):

`protected` modifier means that field can be accessed only from within the class or it's children.

If you want to expose the field, use public:

```
private static bool _invert;

public static bool Invert{

get { return _invert; }
set { _invert = value; }
}
}
```

Comment: This code wont change the Invert Field in the PWM Class though - I have tried this in an inherited class and it does not work.

Comment: So you want to expose _invert_ field that is defined in parent class?

Comment: Yes - see above. I linked to the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear - are you asking how to make a class field visible outside the class?

If so, you can either expose it via a property as you have already done:

```
    public static int PropertyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PropertyName;
        }

        set
        {
            this._PropertyName = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// privatefield for PropertyName 
    /// </summary>
    private static int _PropertyName;
```

Or you can simply declare the field as public. I would always go with the property so I can control what values and under what conditions the value can be set.

Alternative to base class:

```
    public Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.PWM PWM {get;set;}

    public bool PwmBool
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
        set
        {
            this.PWM = new PWM(Cpu.PWMChannel.PWM_4, 10, 0.5, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No no - See message "This code wont change the Invert Field in the PWM Class though - I have tried this in an inherited class and it does not work." I need this to modify another Class Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.PWM

Comment: If that variable in PWM is not readonly, replace _PropertyName with Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.PWM.<varname> in the get and set methods

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen's answer above confirms what I thought, this can not be done. I am attempting the impossible.

Comment: if that property is readonly in the base class, rather than extend the class - expose an instance as a property. You can then use your method setter to reinitialise it.